# Karma Webpack preprocessor is slow

Tags: angularjs, performance, testing, karma-webpack

When running

```
npm run karma -- karma.watch.conf.js --auto-watch --no-single-run
```

with

```
preprocessors: { 'spec-bundle.js': [ 'webpack', 'sourcemap' ] },
```

webpack preprocessor is working for 6-8 minutes, constantly consuming 13% CPU. Simple Can I optimize this somehow?

Simple npm start

```
webpack-dev-server --config webpack.conf.js --progress --profile --colors
```

is ready after about 1 minute.

Comment: you want tests to run each time you make a change?

Comment: @PetrAveryanov, actually, I need both options, for test development I need to run each time I make a change, and for CI build I need to run only once.